# How do I code not supported or defined in vs code

Tags: sql, visual-studio-code

I have set my SQL connection in vs code and it was successful, but when I tried to run SQL statement, it says code language not defined or supported, how can I fix this?

The code I ran was `show databases;`.[This is an image of what I did](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dTxFu.png)

Extensions I installed trying to fix it.
SQL tools Mysql/MariaDB
SQL tools
MySql

Comment: what about the `Run on active connection`, according to the status bar you are not connected

Comment: ok, thanks. I have been able to connect it's asking me to upgrade my MySQL client